# Is it a good practice to use sql in string format in ORM

Tags: c#, jquery, orm

I use sql in string format in ORM (Bltoolkit). I don't prefer to use Linq without need, because

- complex queries are hard to built with Linq. There isn't enough resource for building complex query with Linq.
- with using string sql with ORM, you are still improving your practice of sql querying. Otherwise you have a break with querying(I suppose Linq doesn't improve your sql querying).
- you can still secure your query from sql injection with binding parameters.

What is your idea? Is it  a good practice?

An example for using ORM(for my case, BlToolkit) without Linq is below:

```
        var db = new Veritabani("HstConn");

        try
        {
            var sorgu = @"select t.tcno ""KullaniciAdi"", t.ad ""Ad"", t.soyad ""Soyad"", t.kurum_kodu ""KurumKodu"", 
                                 t.ilkodu ""IlKodu"", t.kurum_turu ""KurumTuru"", t.e_posta ""Eposta"", t.dogrulama_kodu ""DogrulamaKodu""
                            from saglikcalisanlari t
                           where tcno = :kullaniciAdi
                             and sifre = :sifre";

            return db.SetCommand(sorgu,
                                 db.Parameter(":kullaniciAdi", kullaniciAdi.Trim()),
                                 db.Parameter(":sifre", sifre.Trim().Md5Hash())).ExecuteObject<SaglikCalisani>();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw new Exception("Veritabanı Hatası: " + exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Close();
            db.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: Not every question can be boiled down to "what does 1 plus 1 equal?", the question is fine providing people give factual answers and not just opinions.

Comment: @Phill, the OP opens with a whole bunch of opinions about Linq/ORMs, and then proceeds to ask other people about them. Is that not entirely what the 'not constructive' flag is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will always be subjective and context dependent. Perhaps the real question is "will you genuinely target a different db". If the answer to that is "no", then fixed SQL is most likely fine. If you need to target multiple different backends, then an abstraction like HQL or ESQL may be more appropriate - which is different to LINQ, but still platform independent... ish.

There are also plenty of cases where you want to hand-tune the SQL because frankly in complex cases a dev will out-perform a generator (LINQ etc) 9 times out of 10 (according to a study by the EU department of invented statistics).

As long as you correctly parameterize, SQL by itself is fine *in those scenarios*.

stackoverflow.com uses hand-written TSQL *extensively*, because:

- we have no plans to change backend, and if we ever do: the queries are only the tip of the iceberg
- we really really care about performance:

  - parsing an expression tree (LINQ) or a DSL (HSQL/ESQL) to generate TSQL takes time
  - we want the TSQL to be well-written and tested bespokely
  - we were genuinely seeing measured performance issues in the tooling we *were* using, even with precompiled LINQ queries
- we wrote our own tool ("dapper") to remove every feature we didn't *absolutely need* - to make it simply query-in, objects-out
- and our own tool ("mini-profiler") to monitor the performance live on the site

Answer (score 1):

Yes reasons you have mentioned are perfect for opting string format, performance wise you will find very little difference to religiously go for one.

Idea is to use tools that make your more productive without asking you to give up performance of your application.

Like if you like SQL queries over LINQ and are more comfortable with it I dont see any disadvantage in that, on the other hand if you are not going for LINQ because it is taking lot of you and you are finding it difficult its time to push in some effort to learn it. Unless you can compare your tools you cannot choose the best one for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NPoco](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco) - it is based on PetaPoco but has had a few recent enhancements.

Building SQL strings is much easier using the SQL string builder and the latest version also has the ability to use LINQ if you wish.